# WARNING: httplib2.URLError received None <urlopen error [Errno 116] Connection timed out>

Tags: python-2.7

I´ve been searching a solution to this problem but couldn´t find an answer that could solve my problem so far...

I´m trying do download some data from a given https server and this error message keeps popping up...:

WARNING: httplib2.URLError received None

I already tried to enable http and https proxies but without success...

Any hint is welcome!

Cheers

Comment: How are you trying to download data from the server? With, like, a web browser? Or what?

Comment: Try visiting the URL in a browser or using wget, to see if it's really just a httplib2 problem. You need to narrow it down a bit, or give us some more info. Right now, it could be anything...

Comment: Via any web browser I can download the data with no problem. Unfortunately apparently I can´t use wget to download the data I need to use

Specifically I´m trying to download ECMWF data through batch requests using python, as suggested by their website: 

https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/WEBAPI/Accessing+ECMWF+data+servers+in+batch

Thanks again!